# Problema al pedir datos

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con un programa que realiza reservaciones en un hotel, al pedir el piso y el numero de habitación se supone debería decir que se esta disponible y proceder a hacer la reservación, pero prácticamente se salta el primer if y no realiza dicha acción, el problema se medio soluciona dando un espacio en el especificador de datos (%d), pero me obliga a colocar el numero 2 veces por cada variable, he intentado otras formas como fflush pero no soluciona nada.

El programa aún no esta terminado, pero me gusta ir revisando para ver que los procesos vayan correctamente, el problema se encuentra donde inicia el codigo para pedir numero de habitación y piso.

```
printf("¿Elije un piso y habitacion en la que quieras hospedarte, tenemos 5 pisos y cada uno tiene 4 habitaciones\n");
printf("¿Piso numero...?\n");
scanf("%d ", &pis);
printf("¿Habitacion numero...?\n");
scanf("%d ", &habit);
       
if(reserva[pis][habit]==0)
{
    printf("¿Habitacion disponible, reservar S-SI o N-NO?\n");
    scanf("%c", &respuesta);
    if(respuesta=='s' || respuesta=='S')
    {
        reserva[pis][habit]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("¿Desea seleccionar otra habitacion?\n");
        {
            scanf("%c ", &respuesta);
            if(respuesta=='s' || respuesta=='S')
            {
                printf("Empezemos de nuevo entonces\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Hasta pronto\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
else
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar el espacio en tu `scanf`? Es decir, cuando pides el piso y número de habitación, pon: `scanf("%d", &pis);` para el piso y `scanf("%d", &habit);` para la habitación. Por otro lado, intenta postear la mayor información posible, es decir, dónde inicializas tus array bidimensional, qué tipo es, etc.